# bridge two vm interfaces vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I would like to bridge two virtual interfaces on two different VM's in vmware. I tried searching online about this I found out how to bridge a virtual interface to a physical one. Is their a solution for this problem?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software/networking tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a vSwitch on your host, add a network adaptor on both VM's to the vSwitch and you should be all good. Ofcourse there will be no DHCP or anything.....